# SQL Query Syntax Error with percent symbols

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query in an SQLDataSource:

```
SELECT 
   stn_ID, stn_Name, stn_Website, stn_IsDestination, 
   stn_NRCode, stn_NRCodeExist, stn_PostCode, twn_ID 
FROM 
   dbo.tbl_Station AS s 
WHERE 
   (stn_ID NOT IN (SELECT tds_Stn 
                   FROM dbo.tbl_tripDeptStation AS tr 
                   WHERE (tds_Trip LIKE @trip_ID))) 
   AND (stn_Name LIKE %@dept_search%)
```

However I receive a syntax error warning:

> *Incorrect syntax near '@dept_search'.*

How can I correct the error? I require the `%` symbols to be in front and after the parameter, unless there is an alternative method. If I remove these symbols, the query runs correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `%`'s must be in single quotes

`(stn_Name LIKE '%' +@dept_search + '%')`